# Считать имена файлов

Tags: c++, файлы

Есть файл `filename.bin`. В нем данные следующего содержания:

```
file1.txt'\0' Дальше контент..... 
file2.txt'\0' Дальше контент.....
```

Мне нужно "вытащить" имена файлов. Формат:

- имя файла заканчивается '\0'
- размер файла 4 байтовое число в LITTLE_ENDIAN

Comment: Т.е. filename.bin представляет такой простой вид контейнера. Очень интересно может ли быть контент произвольного вида, т.е. содержать заголовок описанного выше формата?

Comment: А что-нибудь про этот "контент" можете сказать?

А лучше просто выложить вывод

     hd filename.bin

Comment: а какая разница, что там за контент?

Comment: Без разницы. Просто чтобы тестировать можно было на реальных данных.

Comment: пара минут и я нагенерировал себе файл. Описание вполне приличное.

Answer (score 1):

Вот идея

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main()
{
    std::ifstream file("filename.bin", std::ios::in | std::ifstream::binary);
    std::string fn;
    int n;
    while (std::getline(file, fn, '\0')) {
        file.read((char*)&n, sizeof(n));
        file.seekg(n, file.cur);
        std::cout << "filename: " << fn << " content size: " << n << std::endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

В коде есть куча особенностей - к примеру, полагается, что sizeof(int) - 4 байта, и файл корректный, и что система, где исполняется, оперирует числами в little-endian.

Comment: Вроде работает. Огромное спасибо!